# Send data from express to client react

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

I'm making a simple register login app to practice express with react. Currently i am validating if the email already exists within the server. What i want to do is when the email is already existing, i want to send some sort of data like how you send a data to template engine such as ejs. But this time i want it on react how would i do this?

```
server.post('/api/register', validateMiddle, (req, res) => {
    db.collection('users').findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    }, (err, succ) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        if(succ){
             // If the same email is found i want to send this kind of data but i want to render it using react
            res.json({message: 'Email already exists!'});
        } else {
            db.collection('users').save(req.body, (err, succ) => {
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    console.log('Success');
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: When you react app makes a `POST` request to your `/api/register` endpoint, the response on your react app should receive `{message: 'Email already exists!'}`. Is this not the case?

Comment: Wow you are right .... i really thought it was coming from the server... i was logging it all this time..

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer. If it helped, can you please mark it correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you react app makes a POST request to your /api/register endpoint, the response on your react app should receive `{message: 'Email already exists!'}.`